# Error indexing method 'Function1'. Cannot bind parameter 'document' to type IAsyncCollector`

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-webjobs

I am getting an Azure Function Error for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host. In my function I'm using CosmosDB. in debug/local its job perfectly but when I open my function in portal I'm getting this error.

> Function (LOANGILITY-AZFUNCTION/ProductDetailsFunc) Error:
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'ProductDetailsFunc'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind
> parameter 'document' to type IAsyncCollector`1. Make sure the
> parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding
> extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure
> you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your
> startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

My Function Header Prototype is

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DocumentDB(
            databaseName: "OB",
            collectionName: "ProductDetails",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnection")]IAsyncCollector<dynamic> document,
        TraceWriter log)
```

Generated json from my code is

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.13",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/Loangility01.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Loangility01.ProductDetailsFunc.Run"
}
```

I also see some other SO questions and they are talking about `builder.something` in the code and I'm not working on .Net Core Azure Function, my target Project Framework is `4.6.1`.

Comment: Is that you use Azure Function V1.0?

Comment: yes I'm using v1

Comment: Is that you want to use Azure Cosmos DB as input or output binding?

Comment: If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp

Comment: Friend yes I'm working with cosmos db in my azure function and it is basically output binding and even I'm saving my data in cosmos db successfully. Only the issue is I'm facing this error in my portal.

Comment: Do you test it on Azure Portal or on-prem?

Comment: When I test my code locally in Visual Studio, it is not giving me any error and it is working fine. But when I deploy it to Azure and I run through Function Url it is giving me `500 Internal Server Error` and when I open Azure Function in portal it is giving me above mentioned error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my test, we can directly deploy Function to Azure via visual studio. But we need to manually configure some settings in local.settings.json such as Cosmos Db connection string. The detailed steps are as below

1. Develop
   My Code:

```
 public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, [DocumentDB(
                databaseName: "ToDoItems",
                collectionName: "Items",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]IAsyncCollector<dynamic> toDoItemsOut, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response ;



            if (name == null) {
                response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");

            }
            else {

                response= req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
            }
            await toDoItemsOut.AddAsync(response.Content);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

2. Deploy to Azure 
   [image]
3. Configure application settings

[image]

[image]

4. Test
   [image]

[image]

**Update**
Regarding the issue, it may be that you do not add your cosmos db connection string into application settings. Please check if you have added.
[image]

Besides if you have added it, you still have the error. You check you logs to get the detailed error message.
[image]

Comment: Friend I was updated my Azure Portal Function version runtime to v1 and my issue was resolved. But now my function is giving me `500 internal server` and not performing anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that we need to be taken care of.

1. Even in v1 for Cosmos DB specifically you have to manually install in the extension that knows how to integrate with CosmosDB. This doc links to the package to install into the project [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#packages---functions-1x)
2. By default when we create Azure function in Azure Portal, it is of version 2; and we need to manually configure for v1 when we're working with v1 Azure function [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version#view-and-update-the-current-runtime-version)

Comment: Friend `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB 1.2.0` already installed in my project.

Comment: Sounds like error only happens when running in cloud. Can you confirm the function in cloud is set to ~1 and not ~2